# Parallelizing a tensorflow operation across multiple GPU's

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

In below code of a single hidden layer neural network I'm attempting to parallelize the gradient descent operation across two GPU's. I'm just attempting to thinking about this conceptually at the moment. There does not appear to be very much literature on how to perform this. Reading [Training Multi-GPU on Tensorflow: a simpler way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029037/training-multi-gpu-on-tensorflow-a-simpler-way) does not provide a concrete answer. In below code I've added two functions `runOnGPU1()` & `runOnGPU1()` which is a conceptual idea of how to split the training of the network across two GPU's. Can these two loops be split in order to share the computation across multiple GPU's ?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# a batch of inputs of 2 value each
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

# a batch of output of 1 value each
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# [!] define the number of hidden units in the first layer
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4 

# connect 2 inputs to 3 hidden units
# [!] Initialize weights with random numbers, to make the network learn
weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# [!] The biases are single values per hidden unit
biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# connect 2 inputs to every hidden unit. Add bias
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

# [!] The XOR problem is that the function is not linearly separable
# [!] A MLP (Multi layer perceptron) can learn to separe non linearly separable points ( you can
# think that it will learn hypercurves, not only hyperplanes)
# [!] Lets' add a new layer and change the layer 2 to output more than 1 value

# connect first hidden units to 2 hidden units in the second hidden layer
weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_UNITS, 2]))
# [!] The same of above
biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

# connect the hidden units to the second hidden layer
layer_2_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(
    tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

# [!] create the new layer
weights_3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 1]))
biases_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

logits = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer_2_outputs, weights_3) + biases_3)

# [!] The error function chosen is good for a multiclass classification taks, not for a XOR.
error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.subtract(logits, desired_outputs) * tf.subtract(logits, desired_outputs))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]

training_outputs = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

def runOnGPU1() : 
    for i in range(5):
        _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                           feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                      desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})
        print(loss)

def runOnGPU2() : 
    for i in range(5):
        _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                           feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                      desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})
        print(loss)

runOnGPU1()
runOnGPU2()
```

Comment: why do the distribution manually? Can't you just setup a distributed tensorflow locally with the parameters on the cpu and the graphs on the gpus? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception has some good illustrations on the setup

Comment: @dv3 are you suggesting to modify https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py to use my training data set  defined in question: training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]] training_outputs = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]] ?